# check version of browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How can i find what version of browser a user is using and ask him to upgrade it

Comment: You can use the user agent, which can be spoofed, and alert them...but it depends what you're after, why do they need to upgrade?  Is there a feature they need that their current one doesn't support?  In that case you should check for that feature's presence.

Comment: how can i check whether the user browser supports that feature or not.

Comment: same: That depends :) Which feature are you looking for? Flash support, opacity support, CSS3 selctors, something else?

Comment: @NickCraver in my case, I want to tell them to update from IE7. >:( They don't know that their browser is outdated, and it's not their responsibility to know because they are institutional users who are not allowed to control the software they use; but I can tell them it's outdated, so that they bother their sysadmins. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` from the `Request.ServerVariables`.

In ASP.NET that would be:

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
```

[More info here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306576)

Answer (score 7):

You can [perform feature detection using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), like this:

```
if (!jQuery.support.opacity)
    //Waah waah waah...
```

You can also [check the browser version using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), like this:

```
if (!jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version === 6)
    //Waah waah waah...
```

However, it should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 2):

On the server-side code: Request.Browser returns a HttpBrowserCapabilities instance with all the information you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx

On the client script side (javascript):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Further to @Nick's comment, the following MSDN post:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx

states:

> Browser capabilities indicate whether
>   the browser type in general supports
>   features such as JavaScript, not
>   whether an individual instance of the
>   browser has these features enabled or
>   disabled.

I think version and type of the browser will tend to be fairly consistent.

Comment: Browser Abilities depends on that info being up to date, which often is *not* the case, not at the rate browsers advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using a javascript library like jQuery or mootools, you also have those tools at your disposal.

jQuery:

```
if( $.browser.msie ) {
 // do something
}
```

mootools:

```
if (Browser.Engine.trident4) {
  // ie6
}
```

keep in mind this is usually the wrong thing to rely on. Even the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) has a warning that recommends [feature detection](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting) instead of browser detection.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about Internet Explorer, you can use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

More info at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:
  alert(navigator.appVersion)
```